# Counts - Can I get multiple counts in a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to build a metrics table for our service desk.

Basically, I am looking to select then insert into a table
UserName 
Count of Tickets 
Tickets Older than 7 Days 
Tickets Older than 30 Days

I have a query built - see below. I can get my count, count older than 7 days and count older than 30 easily by running this 3 times, but is there an easier way? This query is pulling the count of tickets older than 30 days

```
    select xxx.Assignee, count(*) as 'All Assigned'
    from (
    --All Incidents With Assignments
    select i.ticket_number, i.status_1 as Status, i.title, i.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee' from 
    [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a, [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u, 
    [fpscdb008_ws_004].[incidents] i
    where i.id = a.item_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 12610
    and u.app_user_id = a.app_user_id
    and i.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and i.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')
    and i.created_on <= GETDATE() - 30

    Union
    --All SRs With Assignments
    select s.ticket_number, s.status_1 as Status, s.title, s.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee' from 
    [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a, [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u, 
    [fpscdb008_ws_004].[service_request] s
    where a.app_user_id = u.app_user_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 7861
    and s.id = a.item_id
    and s.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and s.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')
    and s.created_on <= GETDATE() - 30

    ) as xxx
    group by xxx.Assignee
    order by xxx.Assignee
```

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting.

Comment: im assuming that if its counted in the greater than 30 it should also be counted in the greater than 7? or are you wanting to exclude them so itd be between 7 and 29?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statement to count:

```
select xxx.Assignee, count(*) as 'All Assigned', 
SUM(CASE WHEN created_on <= GETDATE() - 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Older than 7 days',
SUM(CASE WHEN created_on <= GETDATE() - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Older than 30 days'

from (
    --All Incidents With Assignments
    select i.ticket_number, i.status_1 as Status, i.title, i.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee', s.created_on
    from [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a, [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u, 
    [fpscdb008_ws_004].[incidents] i
    where i.id = a.item_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 12610
    and u.app_user_id = a.app_user_id
    and i.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and i.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')

    Union
    --All SRs With Assignments
    select s.ticket_number, s.status_1 as Status, s.title, s.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee', s.created_on
    from [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a, [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u, 
    [fpscdb008_ws_004].[service_request] s
    where a.app_user_id = u.app_user_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 7861
    and s.id = a.item_id
    and s.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and s.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')

) as xxx
group by xxx.Assignee
order by xxx.Assignee
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE statement to differentiate between the date ranges and also do not use the old JOIN syntax

```
select xxx.Assignee, count(*) as 'All Assigned'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN created_on <= GETDATE() - 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '> 7 days'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN created_on <= GETDATE() - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '> 30 days'
from (
    --All Incidents With Assignments
    select i.ticket_number, i.status_1 as Status, i.title, i.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee', i.created_on
    FROM 
        [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a
    INNER JOIN
        [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u ON u.app_user_id = a.app_user_id
    INNER JOIN
        [fpscdb008_ws_004].[incidents] i ON i.id = a.item_id
    where
        a.item_defn_id = 12610
    and i.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and i.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')

    UNION
    --All SRs With Assignments
    select s.ticket_number, s.status_1 as Status, s.title, s.description,  
    u.user_login as 'Assignee', s.created_on
    FROM 
        [fpscdb008_system].[asgnmt] a
    INNER JOIN
        [fpscdb008_system].[app_user] u ON a.app_user_id = u.app_user_id
    INNER JOIN
        [fpscdb008_ws_004].[service_request] s ON s.id = a.item_id
    WHERE
        a.item_defn_id = 7861
    and s.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and s.status_1 not in ('Closed','Resolved','Cancelled')
) as xxx
GROUP BY xxx.Assignee
ORDER BY xxx.Assignee
```

Comment: Thank you... We have it working.  When I started triplicating the main query, I knew I was on the wrong path.